# Setting a dynamic height for divs in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, height

Check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tdmv7y3L/1/)

This is like a mobile phone prototype where I have fixed height of `50px` for `header-div` and `footer-div`.

I want the `content-div` to dynamically adjust its height according to the `main-container` (which here is acting as mobile screen size). Adjust in such a way that the content overflow should be scrollable in the visible `content-div` height only.

If I put `header-div` and `footer-div` height both `10%` and `content-div` height `80%`. So that it arranges according to the screen size. Trouble here is that the header and footer heights will vary according to screen sizes and as a result will make `header-div` and `footer-div` bigger/smaller in height.

This is why I have set a certain height for `header-div` and `footer-div` both that is `50px`. Now I want the `content-div` to be adjusted in such a way that it dynamically changes its `height` in accordance to the `main-container` (parent div)

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: did you tried vh? https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: No overflow? What if there is too much content? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: please check the edit if it gives you a better idea

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I am not sure if you would like it that way but here's what I've got for you...

*Change your CSS code for `main-container` to this.*

```
 .main-container {
    width: 420px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: Let me know what works and what doesn't, thank you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

change your css code for `main-container`

```
.main-container {
width: 420px;
height: 1.2em; //change as per your requirements 
background-color: #f7f7f7;

}
```

[Web Style Sheets
CSS tips & tricks](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)